# hide test method in child test class

Tags: c#, testing, inheritance, vs-unit-testing-framework, test-class

I have two test classes where one inherits from the other, like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClassBase
{
    // does some actual testing (load file, call methods, do Asserts and such)
    protected virtual DoTest(string fileName) { ... }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFileFoo() { DoTest("fooFile"); }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFileBar() { DoTest("barFile"); }

    ...
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClassChild : TestClassBase
{
    // is just a little bit different from base method
    protected override DoTest(string fileName) { ... }
}
```

I am doing it this way because the `TestClassBase` has around 100 tests that test a certain aspect, and now I added a new functionality that I want to test in the same 100 files in `TestClassChild`. Copy-pasting (i.e. using two classes not connected via inheritance) is no option from maintainability perspective. Some tests are marked with `[Ignore]` (they are not ready yet) which is fine with inheritance because the new functionality is a special case of the old one, i.e. if the old one does not work as expected, it does not make sense to test the new one.

But there is a little difference that doesn't work well with inheritance: **There are some tests (in fact just one) that should be done in `TestClassBase` but not in `TestClassChild`. Is there a way to achieve that?**

Own thoughts:

- I thought I could make that test just `private` instead of `public`, but this does not get along with `[TestMethod]` (which needs `public`).
- Making it `virtual` and overriding it with an empty method would kind of work since the empty method will always pass, but it would confuse others who look at my code. We do not want tests to appear in the test list of `TestClassChild` which are not real tests.
- It would be nice to have `[TestMethod]` conditional in some way, e.g. so that it is only "active" if a certain variable has a certain vaule. Then I could set the variable accordingly in the two test classes.
- Maybe the conditionality could be achieved with precompiler directives? Defining symbols with `#define` and put an `#if`/`#endif` around the `[TestMethod]` line? But how to define the symbol differently in the two classes?

Comment: make a third class and put the method that shouldn't run for TestClassChild there

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You should be testing specifics with your tests, why should a derived class be made to test for another aspect. Are you trying to provide some context to the tests which differ per implementation?

Comment: btw typo in `TestClassChild` shouldn't it be override instead of virtual?

Comment: Doesnt having common methods in test cases (because of two or more child classes inheriting same base class) point to unnecesary/duplicated tests? The test would be executed (same test, same logic) N times, where N is the number of child classes

Comment: @Cleptus Since the actual testing methods differ in every class (note the override), there are no duplicates.

Comment: @Kjara if the logic of the methods differ, then the naming of the methods should be more specific, eliminating the need of inheritance